# A function in C to `push` items to a queue

Tags: c, queue

Using C to write a `push(Queue **, Nod *)` method.  Want to check if I have covered the basics when pushing a `nods` onto the `queue`.

```
void push_back(Queue ** q, Process * p){
    p->next = NULL;
    if( (*q)->head == NULL && (*q)->tail ==NULL){
        (*q)->head = (*q)->tail = p;
    }
    (*q)->tail->next = p->next;
    (*q)->tail = p;
}
```

Am I assigning `NULL` to `(*q)->tail->next` by assigning `p->next` correctly?

Comment: What is the reason to pass a pointer to a pointer to `Queue` here? You don't reassign `q` anywhere so it's just useless redirection happening.

Comment: I think that a pointer to a pointer would allow me to write a function that doesn't need to return the pointer back to a caller

Comment: If you call it like `push_back(&some_queue, some_process)` then you are emulating *call by reference* which is a way so you could reassign the pointer passed as the first argument. Then you could in the function do `*q = some_other_queue`. Since you don't do that you don't need the extra redirection.

Comment: Interesting - I'll try that out

Comment: C does not support _methods_. It is not an OOP language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(*q)->tail->next` should already be `NULL`.

And if the queue is not empty then you don't link in the new node properly. Instead if the queue is not empty you should make `(*q)->tail->next` point to `p` and then make the tail point to `p`:

```
if (/* queue is empty */)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    (*q)->tail->next = p;
    (*q)->tail = p;
}
```

---

And as I said in my comments, you don't seem to need the extra indirection created by passing a pointer to a pointer, which mean you could rewrite it (with my changes) as

```
void push_back(Queue * q, Process * p){
    p->next = NULL;
    if( q->head == NULL && q->tail ==NULL){
        q->head = q->tail = p;
    } else {
        q->tail->next = p;
        q->tail = p;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of this solution but how does `(*q)->tail->next = p` make the `tail` point to `NULL`?  Does `(*q)->tail->next` point to the address of p or does it automatically point to `p->next` which is `NULL`?

Comment: @user5985774 But you don't  *need* the tail to be a null pointer. When you assign `q->tail = p` then afterwards `q->tail->next` will be `NULL` because `p->next` is `NULL`. Try to draw the list on paper, and add new nodes at the head and tail to see how it's done.

Comment: @JJL Also, how else would you make the current tails next pointer point to the new tail (which is `p`)?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but in my case I am initializing a pointer to the Queue, for example `Queue *ready_queue`, and I find that in C the only way for me to pass a pointer to a queue to a method without returning a value is by using that `**` and adding that indirection. Any thoughts? Am I creating this indirection by initializing a pointer to a queue object?

Comment: @JJL Only do it for the functions where you actually does the assignment. In your `push_back` function you don't need it.